# Why does this third tfsbuild command start when the one before it does NOT have the /queue parameter set?

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a batch script which runs four builds, where, in effect, the first two run concurrently and the second two also run concurrently:

EDIT: added **names** which are indicated on each build definition

```
tfsbuild start /queue [params...] name=outputs200

tfsbuild start [params...] name=outputs400

tfsbuild start /queue [params...] name=outputs200

tfsbuild start [params...] name=outputs3*
```

EDIT: on all three build boxes, there are 4 agents with name outputs* (the wildcard will match against naming conventions which make it easy to tell which build box the agent is on)

All four builds are tied to the same Build Controller, and the second and third are (EDIT) **named (not tagged)** such that they never run on the same Agent or on the same machine (I cannot get two installshield builds to work on same box at same time, as they seem to be writing same-named files to temp at same time).

The problem is, even without the queue parameter, the third build starts before the second build completes.

Is this expected before with this arrangement? Or is my Agent tagging scheme incorrect?

Notable: If I remove the the first build from the list, the third build correctly waits until the one before it is complete.

Comment: how many build agents do you have and how are they each tagged? Which build agent does the third build start on? Obviously it is not on the same build agent as second build right?

Comment: Correct, the third is not using same agent as the second. I understand why this doesn't work now, your comment hinted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many build agents do you have and how are they each tagged? Which build agent does the third build start on? Looks like the third build is obviously it is not on the same build agent as second build.

Comment: See my edit. There are no tags, just naming conventions. on all three build boxes, there are 4 agents with name outputs* (the wildcard will match against naming conventions which make it easy to tell which build box the agent is on)

Comment: In a stroke of genius, I decided to just configure the first and second builds as rolling CI builds. This way, all I have to do is run the last two concurrently (which are just the install builds). Thanks for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction - I don't think what I wanted to do was possible with naming or tags alone